# image becomes a little bigger when call css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with a simple CSS animation.

When I call the animation :

```
 .animationSinistra {
  -webkit-animation: animazioneVersoSinistra 3s normal forwards;
  animation: animazioneVersoSinistra 3s normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animazioneVersoSinistra {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(70.5%,22%);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(-30%,10%);
  }
}
```

from

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function animazioneSinistra(){
  document.getElementById('img1').className ='animationSinistra';

}
```

The image has what i thought for my animation, but in the first instant (exactly when I click on the point that make the action start) the image become bigger. Why could it happen even if there is scale(1) in from and to part?

Here the entire code :

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">

  /* == Stili di base - Mobile first ===== */

  /*  Qui vanno gli stili per il mobile

  /* == Media queries (breakpoint) ===== */
  .imageAnimation {
    width:40%;
    height: 40%;
    left:30%;
    top:30%;
  }
  body{
    background-color: #F7F7F7
  }

  /* -----------------------------------
  IPAD PORTRAIT
  ------------------------------------ */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .imageAnimation {
    width:40%;
    height: 40%;
    left:30%;
    top:30%;
  }
  body{
    background-color: #F7F7F7
  }
  }


  /* -----------------------------------
  IPAD LANDSCAPE + NETBOOK
  ------------------------------------ */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    .imageAnimation {
    transform: translate(52%,72%);
    width:50%;
    height: 40%;
    left:26%;
    top:30%;
  }

  .iconaAltoSinistra {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
  }
  .iconaAltoDestra {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 33%;
    left: 72%;
  }
  .iconaBassoDestra {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 64%;
    left: 69%;
  }

  .iconaBassoSinistra {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    top: 64%;
    left: 28%;
  }

  body{
    background-color: #F7F7F7
  }
  }

  /* -----------------------------------
  DESKTOP
  ------------------------------------ */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
      .imageAnimation {
        position: fixed;
        left:50vw;
        top:50vh;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        height: auto;
        width: auto;

  }
    .iconaAltoSinistra {
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      top: 24%;
      left: 31%;
    }
    .iconaAltoDestra {
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      top: 29%;
      left: 67%;
    }
    .iconaBassoDestra {
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      top: 74%;
      left: 64%;
    }

    .iconaBassoSinistra {
      position: absolute;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      top: 70%;
      left: 30%;
    }

    .animationSinistra {
      -webkit-animation: animazioneVersoSinistra 3s normal forwards;
      animation: animazioneVersoSinistra 3s normal forwards;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animazioneVersoSinistra {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(70.5%,22%);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.8) skew(0deg) translate(-30%,10%);
      }
    }


  body{
    background-color: #F7F7F7
  }
  }





  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function animazioneSinistra(){
      document.getElementById('img1').className ='animationSinistra';

    }
    function animazioneDestra(){
      document.getElementById('img').className ='animationDestra';
      document.getElementById('iconaAltoSinistra').className = 'animazioneAltoSinistra';

    }



  </script>
</head>

<body>
<img id = "img1" src="http://www.websocialagency.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WhatsApp-Image-2017-08-30-at-19.47.35.jpeg" class="imageAnimation" alt="logo WebSocialAgency">
<img id = "img" src="http://www.websocialagency.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WhatsApp-Image-2017-08-30-at-19.47.35.jpeg" class="iconaAltoSinistra" alt="logo WebSocialAgency">
<img id = "img" src="http://www.websocialagency.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WhatsApp-Image-2017-08-30-at-19.47.35.jpeg" class="iconaAltoDestra" alt="logo WebSocialAgency" onclick="animazioneSinistra()">
<img id = "img" src="http://www.websocialagency.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WhatsApp-Image-2017-08-30-at-19.47.35.jpeg" class="iconaBassoDestra" alt="logo WebSocialAgency">
<img id = "img" src="http://www.websocialagency.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WhatsApp-Image-2017-08-30-at-19.47.35.jpeg" class="iconaBassoSinistra" alt="logo WebSocialAgency">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I couldn't reproduce this issue. https://jsfiddle.net/o37agevw/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in firefox or chrome either. Perhaps if you could create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: i am using chrome
if u want i can edit with the entire code (the images are 600x600).
ok, the image that I am using is here : http://www.websocialagency.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WhatsApp-Image-2017-08-30-at-19.47.35.jpeg

Comment: Are you sure you haven't scaled the image elsewhere (outside of the animation)?  The `from` merely denotes the starting value, so if that element is scaled elsewhere it'll snap to what you've got in your animation keyframes at the beginning.

Comment: The values in from where the "nearest" values (i tried 1 hour to adjust from values because i thought that the problem was the difference between start position and old position)